# Manipulate CSV file 1 column into multiple - NFL scores

Tags: python, csv

Working on an NFL CSV file that can help me automate scoring for games. Right now, I can upload the teams and scores into ONLY 1 column of the csv file.

THESE ARE ALL IN COLUMN A

Example:
        A

```
1   NYJ
2   27
3   PHI
4   20
5   BUF
6   13
7   DET
8   35
9   CIN
10  27
11  IND
12  10
13  MIA
14  24
15  NO
16  21
```

OR

```
[['NYJ`'], ['27'], ['PHI'], ['20'], ['BUF'], ['13'], ['DET'], ['35'], ['CIN'], ['27'], ['IND'], ['10'], ['MIA'], ['24'], ['NO'], ['21'], ['TB'], ['12'], ['WAS'], ['30'], ['CAR'], ['25'], ['PIT'], ['10'], ['ATL'], ['16'], ['JAC'], ['20'], ['NE'], ['28'], ['NYG'], ['20'], ['MIN'], ['24'], ['TEN'], ['23'], ['STL'], ['24'], ['BAL'], ['21'], ['CHI'], ['16'], ['CLE'], ['18'], ['KC'], ['30'], ['GB'], ['8'], ['DAL'], ['6'], ['HOU'], ['24'], ['DEN'], ['24'], ['ARI'], ['32'], ['SD'], ['6'`], ['SF'], ['41'], ['SEA'], ['22'], ['OAK'], ['6']]
```

What I want is this:

```
   A  B   C  D
1 NYJ 27 PHI 20
2 BUF 13 DET 35
3 CIN 27 IND 10
4 MIA 24 NO  21
```

I have read through previous articles on this and have not got it to work yet. Any ideas on this?

## Any help is appreciated and thanks!

current script:

```
import nflgame
import csv
print "Purpose of this script is to get NFL Scores to help out with GUT"

pregames = nflgame.games(2013, week=[4], kind='PRE')

out = open("scores.csv", "wb")
output = csv.writer(out)

for score in pregames:
    output.writerows([[score.home],[score.score_home],[score.away],[score.score_away]])
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: What is the current format of the CSV file?

Comment: Your edit didn't help at all

Comment: I just edited the post....sorry. Current format is csv

Answer (score 1):

You're currently using `.writerows()` to write 4 rows, each with one column.

Instead, you want:

```
output.writerow([score.home, score.score_home, score.away, score.score_away])
```

to write a single row with 4 columns.

Comment: Thanks Wooble! I thought i tried this before but i guess i didn't. I'm an idiot....thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the score data, try to change writerows to writerow:

```
import nflgame
import csv
print "Purpose of this script is to get NFL Scores to help out with GUT"

pregames = nflgame.games(2013, week=[4], kind='PRE')

out = open("scores.csv", "wb")
output = csv.writer(out)

for score in pregames:
    output.writerow([[score.home],[score.score_home],[score.away],[score.score_away]])
```

This will output it all in one line.